# debug java jar file from command line?

Tags: java, command-line, cucumber-java

I cannot get command-line debugging with jdb to work on a Cucumber/Java jar file. I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842322/how-can-i-debug-a-jar-at-runtime/38357751#38357751) for example, and so far nothing has worked.

- When I run the cucumber feature file from IntelliJ, it works just fine.
- I compiled the program according to the local directions, and that finished successfully.
- When I run the compiled jar file with `java -jar runJar.jar`, everything works just fine.
- When I run `jdb runJar.jar`, I get the jdb prompt:

  Initializing jdb ...

  > 

but when I try to run the Main-Class, it fails:

```
> run MainRunner
run  MainRunner
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Error: Could not find or load main class MainRunner

The application exited
```

I know that "MainRunner" is the correct class because that's the name of the "Main class:" in IntelliJ and also because I unzipped the jar file using this command:

```
unzip -c MyJar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep 'Main-Class
```

and it reports `Main-Class: com.XXXXX.sdt.framework.runner.MainRunner` as the Main-Class.

- If instead `run MainRunner` I type `run com.XXXXX.sdt.framework.runner.MainRunner`, then I get the error:

  VM Started: Error: Could not find or load main class com.XXXXX.sdt.framework.runner.MainRunner
- If I startup a JVM and then attach to it with:

  java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044 -jar runJar.jar

and

```
jdb -attach 1044
```

and resume after the main[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842322/how-can-i-debug-a-jar-at-runtime/38357751#38357751) prompt, I get the error

```
Exception occurred: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (uncaught)"thread=main", java.lang.String.charAt(), line=658 bci=21
```

The Java docs on jdb imply that this should just work, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that you are running `runJar.jar` but checked for the Main class in `MyJar.jar`?

If you are using a JAR file as an application packaging, you need the `Main-Class` in that jar file, not in one of the jar files on your path.